# Is there an equivalent class or module for powershell AzStorageAccount in azure python SDK?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-python-sdk

I'm currently converting Powershell scripts to python scripts using azure python SDK. Is there an equivalent class or module to `AzStorageAccount` to get the list of blob urls using azure python sdk? I check the library azure.mngt.storage doesn't provide me the info i needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package you would want to use to work with data stored in Azure Blob Storage would be `azure-storage-blob` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python). `azure.mngt.storage` is the SDK for managing storage account themselves and do not offer data management capabilities.

The code would be something like:

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

account_url = "https://<storageaccountname>.blob.core.windows.net"
default_credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url, credential=default_credential)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
blob_list = container_client.list_blobs()
for blob in blob_list:
    print("\t" + blob.name)
```

You can find more code samples here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/main/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/samples.

Comment: Thank you for answering but I was looking for a way to get the account_urls of blobs before plugging it up to the code you provided.

Comment: If you know the account name and the region (Azure General, Azure China etc.) where your storage account is located, you can construct the URL using `https://{account-name}.{region-specific-end-point}` pattern. For example, your blob endpoint for storage accounts in Azure General region would always be something like `https://{account-name}.blob.core.windows.net`. However if you do not know the account name in advance, then you will need to use `azure.mngt.storage` to get this information. HTH.

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm trying to look how can I get the account-name but azure.mngt.storage doesn't provide any information on how.

Comment: You may find this link helpful: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-samples-python-management/blob/main/samples/storage/manage_storage_account.py.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem by using `azure.mgmt.storage`. The `storageManagementClient` has a method (`storage_accounts.list()`) that will list all of the storage accounts. Upon checking the data returned, I see that it will also provide the blob URL per account.

```py
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.mgmt.storage import StorageManagementClient

storage_client = StorageManagementClient(credential=DefaultAzureCredential(), subscription_id=subscription_id)
storage_accounts = storage_client.storage_accounts.list()
   
# Get a list of all storage accounts in the subscription
for account in storage_accounts:
    blob_url = account.primary_endpoints.blob
```